# Build dynamic JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to build dynamic json request in java to send to my c++ server. I'm using the GSON library.

This is my json example:

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "12131231231231241": {
                "gToken": {
                    "token": "AABBCCDDEEFF99001122334455667788"
            },
            "objects": {
                "WATER_CONTROL_1": "0"
            }
        },
        "7682642342432423": {
                "userAuthentication": {
                    "userEmail": "user@mail.com",
                    "userPassword": "userPassword"
            },
            "objects": {
                "LIGHT_1_CONTROL": "1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you can see the `nodes` object is dynamic. Inside him i can have a lot of items (in the example i put two, representing by `12131231231231241` and `7682642342432423`). Inside each item the authentication method can be different (by token, by email/password) and inside objects item i can have a lot of different dynamic items too.

The part to send to my c++ server, parse the JSON and do the all validations (authetication for example) is already done and working (i test this json example inside c++ string, encode to json and do the parse, get the all items,etc).

So my problem is to build my class to send the request with some struct to corresponding to this dynamic json.

I already implement some other class to send json to my server and its work because i already know the json expected and on other cases the json have a static/fixed content.

My class for this dynamic json:

```
public class MonitorControlGetRequestArgs implements SerializableJSON {
    Nodes nodes;

    public MonitorControlGetRequestArgs()   {
        nodes = new Nodes();
    }

    static class Nodes{
        public Nodes(){
        }
    }


    public static MonitorControlGetRequestArgs fromStringJson(String data){
        try {   
        Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.fromJson(data, MonitorControlGetRequestArgs.class);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static MonitorControlGetRequestArgs fromBytesJson(byte[] data){
        if (data == null)
            return null;
        try {
            String str = new String(data, "utf-8");
            return fromStringJson(str); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toJsonString(){
        try{
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.toJson(this);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] toJsonBytes(){
        try {
            return this.toJsonString().getBytes("utf-8");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I create a `static class Nodes` empty to show you. In my server c++ i receive the item `nodes` in json format, but now i have a lot of doubts how to build the struct inside `nodes` to corresponding to my dynamic json.

I hope you understand my doubts. If you don't understand something tell to me.

EDIT 1 - (try to use the example of Andriy Rymar)

I try to simulate this json:

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "1317055040393017962": {
            "userAuthentication": {
                "userEmail": "rr@rr.com",
                "userPassword": "rr123"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My request class:
    public class MonitorControlGetRequestArgs implements SerializableJSON
    {
        private final static String nodeTemplate = "\"%s\":%s";
        List nodes = new ArrayList<>();

```
    public MonitorControlGetRequestArgs(UserAuthentication userAuthentication)
    {
        JsonData jsonData = new JsonData();
        jsonData.addNode(new Node("1317055040393017962", new NodeObject(userAuthentication)));
    }

    static class Node 
    {
        private final String nodeName;
        private final Object nodeBody;

        public Node(String nodeName, Object nodeBody) {
          this.nodeName = nodeName;
          this.nodeBody = nodeBody;
        }

        public String getNodeName() {
          return nodeName;
        }

        public Object getNodeBody() {
          return nodeBody;
        }
    }

    static class JsonData {

        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addNode(Node node){
          nodes.add(node);
        }
      }

    static class NodeObject
    {
        UserAuthentication userAuthentication;

        public NodeObject(UserAuthentication userAuthentication)
        {
            this.userAuthentication = userAuthentication;
        }
    }

    public static MonitorControlGetRequestArgs fromStringJson(String data)
    {
        try
        {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.fromJson(data, MonitorControlGetRequestArgs.class);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static MonitorControlGetRequestArgs fromBytesJson(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null) return null;
        try 
        {
            String str = new String(data, "utf-8");
            return fromStringJson(str); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toJsonString()
    {
        try
        {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.toJson(this);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] toJsonBytes()
    {
        try 
        {
            return this.toJsonString().getBytes("utf-8");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2

I will try to explain better,i believe I was not totally explicit. My application java is a REST application that send json to my c++ server. In my server i receive the json, i do the parse, i do the validation, the operations, etc and return back to my java client the response in json too.

For example, imagine that my json request body (to create a new user for example) is something like this:

```
{
    "userInformation": {
        "name": "user name",
        "age": 33
    }
}
```

For this i don't have any doubts how to do (i already implement a lot of requests very similar). I can create a static class like this:

```
static class UserInfo
{
   String name;
   String age;

   public UserInfo(String name, String age)
   {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
   }
}
```

And inside a request class (very similar to a class like i copy before -  `MonitorControlGetRequestArgs`) i create a new instance to my `UserInfo`

```
UserInfo userInformation = new UserInfo (name, age)
```

In this case its easy because the request json body is static. I already now that i have a `userInformation` section and inside i have a name and age. To create a list with `userInfo` (to create multiple users at same time for example) i already implement things like this.

But now, for this specific case i have this json:

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "12131231231231241": {
                "gToken": {
                    "token": "AABBCCDDEEFF99001122334455667788"
            },
            "objects": {
                "WATER_CONTROL_1": "0"
            }
        },
        "7682642342432423": {
                "userAuthentication": {
                    "userEmail": "user@mail.com",
                    "userPassword": "userPassword"
            },
            "objects": {
                "LIGHT_1_CONTROL": "1"
                 "LIGHT_3_CONTROL": "0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in this case i have some problems. In these example i put two items (12131231231231241,7682642342432423) but the user can send more (3,4,5,50,100). In the other hand inside `nodes` i have two sections (12131231231231241,7682642342432423) but this numbers are some ids that i use in my app and i never know that ids the user will put. In last example ( `userInformation` ) its simple because i create a `userInformation` section because i already know that the user always put this section, it is static. In these new json request i dont know, because i never now what value he put, i only know that is a string. The authentication method i dont have problems to create. But other problem that i expected to have is in objects section, because the user can put to a lot of objects and i never know what is the key (in `userInformation` i know that the keys are always the name and age for example and only exits these two keys, i these new case i dont know what is the keys and what are the number of pair of keys/values he put).

EDIT 3 -

I implement this code and i could almost produce all the structure I need. I'm using the gson same.

```
Nodes nodes;

public MonitorControlGetRequestArgs(String userEmail, String userPassword, Map <String,String> objects)
{
    nodes = new Nodes(userEmail, userPassword, objects);
}

static class Nodes
{
    AuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod;
    Map <String,String> objects;

    public Nodes(String userEmail, String userPassword, Map <String,String> objects)
    {
        authenticationMethod = new AuthenticationMethod(userEmail, userPassword);
        this.objects = objects;
    }
}
```

The result json:

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "authenticationMethod": {
            "userAuthentication": {
                "userEmail": "user@mail.com",
                "userPassword": "userPassword"
            }
        },
        "objects": {
            "aa": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
            "bbbbbbb": "bbbbb",
            "ccdd": "ccddccdd"
        }
    }
}
```

Know i only need to add some struct to support this json:

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "7682642342432423": {
            "authenticationMethod": {
                "userAuthentication": {
                    "userEmail": "user@mail.com",
                    "userPassword": "userPassword"
                }
            },
            "objects": {
                "0": "Hammersmith & City",
                "1": "Circle",
                "dasd": "dasda"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The objects is a map, so i can put the number of objects string/string that i want. Know i need to do something to support the previous json with the 7682642342432423, 12131231231231241, etc, etc..

EDIT 4 - final

```
Map <String, Obj> nodes;

    public MonitorControlGetRequestArgs(Map <String, Obj> nodes)
    {
        this.nodes = nodes; 
    }

    static class Obj
    {

        AuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod;
        Map <String,String> objects;

        public Obj(String userEmail, String userPassword, Map <String,String> objects)
        {
            authenticationMethod = new AuthenticationMethod(userEmail, userPassword);
            this.objects = objects;
        }


    }
```

Json that arrive in my server (like i want)

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "12131231231231241": {
            "authenticationMethod": {
                "userAuthentication": {
                    "userEmail": "user@mail.com",
                    "userPassword": "userPassword"
                }
            },
            "objects": {
                "aa": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "bbbbbbb": "bbbbb",
                "ccdd": "ccddccdd"
            }
        },
        "777777777777777": {
            "authenticationMethod": {
                "userAuthentication": {
                    "userEmail": "user@mail.com",
                    "userPassword": "userPassword"
                }
            },
            "objects": {
                "aa": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "bbbbbbb": "bbbbb",
                "ccdd": "ccddccdd"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit this, and put a sentence at the top stating what your problem is?  It's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: If you have different objects inside your `nodes` array then you have to define general interface (or base class) for all your object types. Then implement your JSON container class where is 'List<YOUR_GENERIC_INTERFACE> nodes = new ArrayList()' field. Then populate this list of all object that you need and it will be serialized to JSON string that you are expecting.

Comment: Unrelated: please don't send passwords in plaintext

Comment: @JeffUK my problem is how to build my request class to follow my dynamic json

Comment: @JonK its a user and password random only to this example

Comment: @AndriyRymar the nodes they are not a array, it is a simple json object

Comment: You could just store your data in a set of maps and convert that to json

Comment: @RMRMaster ok, got it. Then there no way to build dynamic objects in Java. You may use some other structures, like `Map`, `List` etc and then implement your JSON serializer to serialize it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for you reply tddmonkey and Andry.. i will try. I'm new with java, i'm better able with c ++ :)

Comment: You have some example how to this?

Comment: In the other hand, not exist some way to pick my request body and use gson to convert all to json without using structures?  Its not possible to convert all body directly to json using gson instead using a object of my class in gson?

Comment: @tddmonkey i need help

Comment: @AndriyRymar i need help

Comment: I'm trying a two hours ago implement this but i cannot understand how to do .. i search a lot of examples but i dont found anything that can help me.

Note: Of course i'm not searching the code to copy and past.. i'm trying to understand how to implement this.. i need to finish this part of project and i'm spending a lot of hours and i cannot find any solution

Comment: @RMRMaster Can you use something else instead of Gson ? For example OrgJson ?

Comment: Yes i think i can use (i cant try). In these case i can convert directy my json body request (string) directly to json format? Because with gson i need to create objects, and for this particular case i think its very hard

Comment: @RMRMaster, please find my answer below. It works as you need but in case of JSON libraries that allow do manage nodes (unlike Gson that allow only to serialize / deserialize objects) the code will be better and clear. P.S. On my example I'm using `Java 8` and `Gson 2.8.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is improved code from previous example that is more flexible and has better serialization mechanism :

```
public class ForTestApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    NodeArray jsonContainer = new NodeArray(
        new Node("nodes",  new NodeArray(
            new Node("12131231231231241", new NodeArray(
                new Node("gToken",
                    new Node("token", "AABBCCDDEEFF99001122334455667788")),
                new Node("objects", new NodeArray(
                    new Node("WATER_CONTROL_1", "0"),
                    new Node("WATER_CONTROL_2", "1")
                )))),
            new Node("7682642342432423", new NodeArray(
                new Node("userAuthentication", new NodeArray(
                    new Node("userEmail","user@mail.com"),
                    new Node("userPassword","userPassword")
                )),
                new Node("objects", new NodeArray(
                    new Node("WATER_CONTROL_1", "0"),
                    new Node("WATER_CONTROL_2", "1")
                ))
            ))
        )));

    System.out.println(jsonContainer.toJSONString());
  }

}

class NodeArray {
  private static final String NODE_TEMPLATE = "\"%s\":%s";
  private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

  private List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

  public NodeArray(Node... nodes){
    addNode(nodes);
  }

  public void addNode(Node... node){
    nodes.addAll(Arrays.asList(node));
  }

  public String toJSONString() {

    return nodes.stream()
        .map(node -> String.format(NODE_TEMPLATE, node.getNodeName(), getNodeBodyAsJSON(node)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "{", "}"));
  }

  private String getNodeBodyAsJSON(Node node) {
    if (node.getNodeBody() instanceof NodeArray) {
      return ((NodeArray) node.getNodeBody()).toJSONString();
    }
    return gson.toJson(node.getNodeBody());
  }

}

class Node {
  private final String nodeName;
  private final Object nodeBody;

  public Node(String nodeName, Object nodeBody) {
    this.nodeName = nodeName;
    this.nodeBody = nodeBody;
  }

  public String getNodeName() {
    return nodeName;
  }

  public Object getNodeBody() {
    return nodeBody;
  }
}
```

The output of such application is :

```
{"nodes":{"12131231231231241":{"gToken":{"nodeName":"token","nodeBody":"AABBCCDDEEFF99001122334455667788"},"objects":{"WATER_CONTROL_1":"0","WATER_CONTROL_2":"1"}},"7682642342432423":{"userAuthentication":{"userEmail":"user@mail.com","userPassword":"userPassword"},"objects":{"WATER_CONTROL_1":"0","WATER_CONTROL_2":"1"}}}}
```

Pretty view is :[image]

NOTICE : this example use constructors to build complex structures but I highly recommend to use **builder** pattern for such case. Code will be clearer and better.

Comment: So if you don't know exact values of your data or size etc. it is doesn't matter for this approach. Just build your `NodeArray` using your data structure in similar way. (Or rework it to use builder pattern)

Comment: Thanks for the example. I think i understand your code. In you code you put the content manually (12131231231231241, etc etc).. But its possible to create nodeArray without content manually? I think its this part that i'm having some doubs or problems

Comment: In class example (MonitorControlRequestGet) that i put in this post, in fromStringJson() function i return a new gson with object of my class

Comment: Yes, to create such object structure you can use any comfortable to you approach (builders, cycles etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I understand the idea but i'm a still bit confuse. Its possible to use static class like i do to other json requests? I'm confuse in this right part, to create this object structure

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being a bit noob, but I've never worked much with java at this level

Comment: @RMRMaster, why do you need static classes ? Try to read more about difference. I guess there no reason to use static classes. If your problem is to build such object structure you have to describe from which data you try to do it. If you have several objects that coming from uses and you have to aggregate them into such structure and then send to your server then just use `add` method after parsing each object and build structure as well. My example shows that it is possible to handle complex structure in Java and serialize it to JSON according to requirement.

Comment: Yes, i dont said that i need to use static classes, its only a example. 

You seed my MonitorControlGetRequestArgs in main question? In this class i have the function fromStringJson() that receive one string. This string contains the all user request body, and in this function i pick this string and convert to gson object class. I need to prepare this class to build json equal to the json that i already put before with the nodes

Comment: Like i said for me its easy to build one class when i already know what all sections that the json need, the keys, values, etc.

Comment: You are understanding my real doubt/problem?

Comment: You are understanding my real doubt/problem?

Like i said before too its easy to create in java a struct to a json that have a section called for example "userInformation", because i already know that for all requests the user put this section ("userInformation").. but for this particular cases how to build in java the struct object to have a section with the 12131231231231241 or 7682642342432423 or other value.. this values its not static, the userInforation are for example... this is my real problem.. because in this case i dont know how to do this..

Comment: Yes, please provide example of input jsons that should be aggregated to single. In worst case I suggest you to use OrgJson, there is possibility to iterate trough JSON fields and elements, using such approach you may generate desired JSON from other JSONs without converting to Java. Currently you cans create Java object from JSON that structure is unknown.

Comment: I already provide a example, I have a nodes section an inside nodes section i have a dynamic number of sections. The user can send 1,2,10,500, etc. For each sections i have a section userAuthentication and other sections called objects.. inside objects i can have a lot of keys/pars (1,2,3,50,100,etc.. the user choose how many want to send).. this is the the exactly example that i already put in the question )

Comment: Then try to use any JSON library that allow manipulation with data inside without deserialization to objects. Then you will be flexible enough to build any JSON you need without objects and issues with serialization/deserialization

Comment: So for this case its not possible to use gson? The application and all other requests have the same structure for both the client and server side, it is rather complicated to change everything to use a JSON library.

Comment: It is possible to use Gson but it's require as many objects as you have JSON structures to satisfy deserialization, and then you have to collect this objects somehow and then build algorithm, similar to what I provided, to serialize them back to JSON . Writing application that works only with JSON, manage fields and produce another JSON is much flexible.

Comment: In my static function fromStringJson() its possible to pick the string data and use inside this function other json library? I'm asking this because i really need to maintain the app struct.. Its really hard change all project and their struct just because this request...

Comment: I only need inside this function, convert this String data to json format.. but i need to maintain the function in static mode...you know how to do this?

Comment: Sure, you can include any other library and use it exactly in that case (it is bad practice to use many libraries aimed to do the same, but any way it might by your approach). Any way if you has JSON where some parts are unknown , for example keys, then it is impossible to map it to java object using `gson`. You have to use simple JSON 2 JESON transformation and thats is all, without any java objects and tones of classes. Just work with JSON data as is, iterating trough keys and values.

Comment: See my edit 3 please.. i almost implement the struct to all my json using gson. If you see the edit 3 you can see what is the only thing that is missing

Comment: My only doubt know is how to add the 12131231231231241, 7682642342432423, 84844494949494, to my nodes Struct and for each number i need to add the AuthenticationMethod and Objectes map, like i already show here

Comment: Thanks for you help :) I'm very grateful.. I already implement all struct in my java client to produce the json that i want using the gson :) 

See edit 4 to see all final struct ;)

Comment: Thanks ;) It was simpler than I thought :)

Comment: @Andry Rymar, remember this post? I have another doubt, can you try to help me?

Comment: @RMRMaster, yes, please, go ahead with your question.

Comment: @Andry Rymar thanks again. I already some the problem. Best for you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of what you need using Gson. But if you would like to use something else, for example OrgJson then the code will be more clear and without String templates.

```
public class ForTestApplication {
  private final static String nodeTemplate = "\"%s\":%s";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JsonData jsonData = new JsonData();

    jsonData.addNode(new Node("user-1", new TestObject(62, "James", "Gosling")));
    jsonData.addNode(new Node("user-2", new TestObject(53, "James", "Hetfield")));

    System.out.println(jsonData.toJSONStirng());
  }


  static class JsonData {

    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addNode(Node node){
      nodes.add(node);
    }

    public String toJSONStirng() {
      Gson gson = new Gson();

      return nodes.stream()
          .map(node -> String.format(nodeTemplate, node.getNodeName(), gson.toJson(node.getNodeBody())))
          .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "{", "}"));
    }
  }

  static class Node {
      private final String nodeName;
      private final Object nodeBody;


    public Node(String nodeName, Object nodeBody) {
      this.nodeName = nodeName;
      this.nodeBody = nodeBody;
    }

    public String getNodeName() {
      return nodeName;
    }

    public Object getNodeBody() {
      return nodeBody;
    }
  }

  static class TestObject {
    private int age;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public TestObject(int age, String firstName, String lastName) {
      this.age = age;
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
      return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
    }
  }

}
```

Output :

```
{"user-1":{"age":62,"firstName":"James","lastName":"Gosling"},"user-2":{"age":53,"firstName":"James","lastName":"Hetfield"}}
```

Pretty view :
[image]

Comment: wow, thanks for this post. I really think it can help me. 

You add "manually" the "user-1" and "user-2".. in my can its works? Because in my case i never know what "key" the user send in body request

Comment: yes, you can add any `Object` and it will works. Happy that this helped you.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will work now seeing your example. Really thanks ;) If i have some doubts i write.

Comment: In my case i think i only need the Gson to serialize / deserialize.. because this java client application its only to send and receive the response.. to manage the json data and process the response back in json, i do this in my server c++

Comment: @Andry Rymar can you see my "Edit 1" in main question? I try to adapt your example code to my request class but i have some difficulties.

And sorry again but like i said i'm new with java programming and i only know the basic. But for this case i have some difficulties

Comment: My fromStringJson(String data) in my class is call on other class that get the request body and send to fromStringJson() function, and we need to be static

Comment: @RMRMaster sorry but I can't understand what you trying to do in your example. Can you describe what you trying to do and where is the issue?

Comment: @RMRMaster in my example I used static classes because I created an example in a single file class. In real life it is bad practice, you have to develop different classes and use SOLID principles.

Comment: @RMRMaster is your problem to build objects from JSON? If yes then its require custom parsing as my example use `Object` type for body content, simple deserialization can't work in that case. But if you still need to serialize objects to JSON, then I see you added additional wrapper called `NodeObject ` and it might be an issue.

Comment: i put a new edit (edit 2). Sorry for the long text but now i believe that i explain correctly the all things with some examples.

Thanks again for you help.

Comment: @RMRMaster Why it is and issue that you don't know keys ? To create JSON you just need to know what is key and use it as key but what it is exactly (value) doesn't matter. I will try to create example for JSON from your description

Comment: Thanks again @Andriy Rymar. Yes, i believe in you but for this case in java i'm having some doubts how to building this struct. Ok, i will wait for the example, thanks again.

You understand know my problem? :)